# Trying to understand an equation for predicting baseball, specifically a comma?

Tags: statistics

I'm reading a paper about predicting baseball games, and I'm having trouble figuring out what one of the variables means. It's the "r1, r2, and r3" variables in the following passage:

> It is unreasonable to expect that all three ratios affect the
> probability of winning in the same way. We therefore adopt unknown
> contribution parameters r=(r1,r2,r3) where we define the relative
> strength of the home team over the visiting team at time s as
>
> λs=α^r1∗β^r2∗γ^r3
>
> We assume that the contribution parameters are
> constant across all MLB teams and arise from independent prior
> distributions with ri ∼uniform(0,ai)where ai is prescribed, i=1,2,3. The
> value ri close to 0 implies that the corresponding ratio has little
> effect on the relative strength. For the MLB data considered in this
> paper, we let ai =2 for i =1,2,3. We view these as subjective priors
> where we use our knowledge of MLB to impose effects based on the
> current winning percentage, batting and pitching. Note that in the
> context of the models described below, ai
> = 2 is a realistic upper bound for the value of ri , i=1,2,3.

I don't understand what they mean by

> ri ~ uniform(0,ai)

This r variable is responsible for weighting the particular variables involved in this prediction, so it seems to be pretty important that I know how to calculate it. Thank's in advance.

Edit: Here is the paper in question: [http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~tim/papers/mlb.pdf](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/%7Etim/papers/mlb.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It means they expect the $r_i$ to be uniformly (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) distributed across all possible match-ups with a mean of $\bar{r_i} = \frac{a_i}{2}$ and $r_i \in [0, a_i] = [0, 2]$.

Also, for better understanding, please provide a link to the paper in question.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So r1, r2, and r3 are all set to = 2?

Comment: Sorry, the notation suggests a mean of $a_i/2$ with values $r_i \in [0, a_i]$. I have misread.

Comment: I edited in a link to the paper.